# Invoking a method within a generic type class

Tags: java, generics

Suppose that we have 2 classes A,B:

```
class A extends SomeClass {
   public String getProp() {
      return "propA";
   }
}

class B extends SomeOtherClass{
   private String propB;

   public B setProp(String value) {
      propB = value;
      return this;
   }

   public String getProp() {
      return propB;
   }
}
```

and suppose that we have another class called X and this class X has a method someMethod that takes a reference to any of these classes ,is there a way that we can use generics in this method to call getProp() according to the object that has been passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this can be considered an answer , but I don't like it..

```
public class X<T>{
public void someMethod(T t) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
    t.getClass().getMethod("getProp", null).invoke(t, null);
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    X<A> weird = new X<>();
    A a = new A();
    weird.someMethod(a);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Not using generics.

You can define a common *interface* for these classes that has the getProp() method. The method using it should then accept an instance of the interface, and can call the `getProp()` method on the interface, which will be implemented by the concrete class you pass in.

Comment: Well, the shorter answer would be "No".

Answer (score 0):

Generics is meant for type-safety at compile time and not for achieving polymorphism at run-time. So I don't think what you're asking is possible.

In your scenario, you should consider creating an interface. Something like this:

```
public interface PropInf{
  String getProp();
}
```

You would then have to implement this interface in both your classes. Using a reference variable of this interface, you can then achieve polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `interface` as follows:

```
interface StringPropProvider {
  String getProp();
}
```

then define your classes to *implement* that interface:

```
class A extends SomeClass implements StringPropProvider {
   public String getProp() {
    return "propA";
}

class B extends SomeOtherClass implements StringPropProvider {
  private String propB;

  public B setProp(String value) {
    propB = value;
    return this;
  }

  public String getProp() {
    return propB;
  }
}
```